# How to accept List<string> in API controller's method from body as json?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'd want to send to my API controller's method json like this:

```
{
    "lines":
    [
        "asd1",
        "asd2"
    ]
}
```

[image]

I've been trying those params

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Test([FromBody]List<string> lines)
{

}


[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Test([FromBody]string[] lines)
{

}


[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Test([FromBody]string lines)
{

}
```

But it's always either empty or null

Any idea?

Comment: That's because the json you're sending it is an object, with a property named "lines", which contains the list. Either change the json to be *only* `["asd1", "asd2"]`, or change the API to accept this object.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen Thanks, please write it as an answer, so I can accept

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There is a mismatch between your JSON input and your accepted parameters.

The parameter matching doesn't (at least to my knowledge) allow you to wrap the parameters inside an object.

Instead, the JSON will be passed in as 1 parameter to your API.

The problem here is that your JSON input contains an object, with a property named "lines", that contains your list, whereas your API only accepts that list.

So you have two options:

1. Change your JSON so that it only contains the list (array) of strings

   ie. pass this in *instead* of the JSON you have now:

   ```
   ["asd1", "asd2"]
   ```

   *(in other words, that is your whole input, remove `{ "lines":` and `}`)*
2. Change your API to accept an object

   ```
   public class LinesParameter
   {
       public List<string> Lines { get; } = new List<string>();
   }

   public IActionResult Test([FromBody]LinesParameter lp)
   ```

Either one of these should work, you will have to decide yourself which one you want to go for.

Answer (score 6):

post `array` of strings only like -> `["str1", "str2"]` and then change controller to

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Test( [FromBody] List<String> lines)
{

}
```